# Uniqueness of quasi-inverses in infinity categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

I've been trying to learn some of the basic language of infinity-category theory (in the sense of Lurie), and in particular, to understand which basic statements in (1-)categories have analogues in the infinity-categorical setting. Specifically, I'm trying to understand how equivalences behave in infinity categories, motivated by the following question.

> **Vague Question:** in an infinity-category $\mathcal C$, to what extent is it true that a quasi-inverse to a morphism $f$, if it exists, is unique up to a contractible space of choices?

Here is how I believe this question should be made precise. If we let $I$ denote the nerve of the undirected interval category (the category with two objects and exactly one morphism between each pair of objects), then there is an inclusion $\Delta^1\hookrightarrow I$ coming from the inclusion of the directed interval category in the undirected interval category. Thus we have a restriction map
$$\mathcal C^I\rightarrow\mathcal C^{\Delta^1}$$
of simplicial sets (in fact a functor of infinity-categories which is a fibration for the Joyal model structure), where informally the left-hand side is the infinity-category of quasi-inverse pairs $(g,h)$ of morphisms in $\mathcal C$ (with a family of homotopies realising their quasi-inverseness), the right-hand side is the infinity-category of arrows in $\mathcal C$, and the functor takes a pair $(g,h)$ to its first component $g$.

> **Precise Question:** if $f$ is a morphism in an infinity-category $\mathcal C$, is it true that the fibre of the map $\mathcal C^I\rightarrow\mathcal C^{\Delta^1}$ over the point $f$ of $\mathcal C^{\Delta^1}$ is either empty or a contractible Kan complex?

I am interested both in answers to the precise question and the vague questions above, especially if there are alternative precise formulations which make the answer clearer.

---

**Remark:**

The condition that $f$ admit a quasi-inverse should be be equivalent to the assertion that it be an isomorphism in the homotopy category of $\mathcal C$. This is asserted in [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+in+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category) nlab page, and something similar in the language of topological categories is proved in the setting of topological categories in Proposition 1.2.4.1 of *Higher Topos Theory*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibly simpler way of proving what you are after is using *marked simplicial set*.

Recall that marked simplicial sets are pairs $(X,S)$ where $X$ is a simplicial set and $S\subseteq X_1$ is a set of 1-simplices of $X$ containing all degenerate 1-simplices. If $X$ is a simplicial set we will denote the minimal and maximal marking by $X^\flat$ and $X^\sharp$ respectively

If $X,Y$ are two marked simplicial sets, we can form additional simplicial sets $\mathrm{Map}^\flat(X,Y)$ and $\mathrm{Map}^\sharp(X,Y)$ by
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sSet}}(K,\mathrm{Map}^\flat(X,Y))=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sSet}^+}(K^\flat\times X,Y)\,,$$
$$ \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sSet}}(K,\mathrm{Map}^\sharp(X,Y))=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{sSet}^+}(K^\sharp\times X,Y)\,.$$

In HTT.3.1.3.7 a simplicial model structure is constructed on the category of marked simplicial sets such that the fibrant objects are precisely the $\infty$-categories with the equivalences marked.

The important part here will be that

- For any anodyne morphism of simplicial sets $A\to B$ the map $A^\sharp\to B^\sharp$ is a marked trivial cofibration. This is because of the definition of marked trivial cofibration (HTT.3.1.3.3) and the fact that for any simplicial set $A$ and every $\infty$-category $C$
  $$ \mathrm{Map}^\sharp(A^\sharp,C)=\mathrm{Map}(A,\mathrm{Core}(C))$$
- If $f:X\to Y$ is a marked trivial cofibration and $C$ is a fibrant object (i.e. an $\infty$-category with the equivalences marked), then the map
  $$f^*:\mathrm{Map}^\flat(B,C)\to \mathrm{Map}^\flat(A,C)$$
  is a trivial fibration (HTT.3.1.3.3)

Then we can factorize the arrow you want to study as
$$C^J=\mathrm{Map}^\flat(J^\sharp,C)\to \mathrm{Map}^\flat((\Delta^1)^\sharp, C)\to \mathrm{Map}^\flat((\Delta^1)^\flat,C)=C^{\Delta^1}$$
The first arrow is a trivial fibration and the second is precisely the inclusion of the subcategory of $C^{\Delta^1}$ spanned by the equivalences.

Comment: This is a very neat argument! In your final line, when you assert that $\mathrm{Map}^\flat(J^\sharp,C)\rightarrow\mathrm{Map}^\flat((\Delta^1)^\sharp,C)$ is a trivial fibration, you mean for the Joyal model structure, right?

Comment: @AlexanderBetts Trivial fibrations for the Kan or the Joyal model structure are the same thing (since the cofibrations are the same). They are Kan fibrations with contractible fibers

Comment: @AlexanderBetts Essentially the result you want can be stated as saying that $(\Delta^1)^\sharp\to I^\sharp$ is a marked anodyne morphism. I am pretty sure there must be a more direct proof of that, but I don't see it.

Comment: The map $j : (Δ^1)^{\sharp} \to J^{\sharp}$ is (marked anodyne because it is) a transfinite composition of pushouts of maps of the form HTT.3.1.1.1.(2) followed by a pushout of a map of the form HTT.3.1.1.1.(4).

Comment: @DanielGerigk I suspected as much, but I don't quite see how to get the sequence of pushouts. Would you like to write a little more details (either in comments or in a new answer)?

Comment: @DenisNardin Sure. You iteratively fill horns of the form HTT.3.1.1.1.(2), i.e. $(\Lambda^n_n,\mathcal{E} \cap (\Lambda^n_n)_1) \subseteq (\Delta^n,\mathcal{E})$, first for n=2, then for n=3, and so on. The vertices $n,n−1,n−2,n−3,\dots$ of $\Lambda^n_n$ are sent to the vertices $1,0,1,0,\dots$ of the simplicial set that you've constructed so far, starting with $(\Delta^1)^{\sharp}$. Finally you need to compose with a pushout of a map of the form HTT.3.1.1.1.(4) because you want the edge going from the vertex 1 to the vertex 0 to be marked, too. I think I have …

Comment: … seen that argument somewhere once, but I can't quite remember where.

Comment: I think the construction is slightly more amenable if we replace the class of marked anodyne maps with its opposite, which is obtained by replacing $(\Lambda^n_n, \mathcal{E} \cap (\Lambda^n_n)_1) \subseteq (\Delta^n,\mathcal{E})$ in HTT.3.1.1.1.(2) by $(\Lambda^n_0, \mathcal{E}' \cap (\Lambda^n_0)_1) \subseteq (\Delta^n,\mathcal{E}')$, where $\mathcal{E}'$ denotes the set of degenerate edges of $\Delta^n$ together with the edge going from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 4):

If $C$ is a category, its *core* is the subgroupoid consisting of the isomorphisms of $C$. This generalizes; if $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\infty$-category, we define its *core* is the $\infty$-subgroupoid consisting only of equivalences.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a quasi-category, define $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})$ by the following pullback of simplicial sets:

$$ \require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})  @>>> \mathcal{C}
\\ @VVV @VVV
\\ \mathbf{N}(\mathrm{Core}(\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C})) @>>> \mathbf{N}(\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C})
\end{CD} $$
The bottom horizontal map is an inner fibration because it is a functor between (nerves of) categories (introduction to HTT section 2.3). I think you can show the right vertical map is an inner fibration as well. Therefore, $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})$ is a quasi-category. (and furthermore, this diagram computes a pullback in the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-categories)

HTT propositions 1.2.5.1 and 1.2.5.3 together imply that $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})$ is the maximal Kan subcomplex of $\mathcal{C}$. And by construction, we can see a morphism of $\mathcal{C}$ is in $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})$ if and only if it is an isomorphism in the homotopy category.

(the remarks following the proof of 1.2.5.3 state this construction is actually right adjoint to the inclusion $\mathbf{Kan} \to \mathbf{QuasiCat}$)

Since $\Delta^1 \to I$ is a Kan equivalence, it follows that there is an equivalence of $\infty$-groupoids
$$ \mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})^I \to \mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})^{\Delta^1} $$
and the objects of $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal{C})^{\Delta^1} \subseteq \mathcal{C}^{\Delta^1}$ are precisely functors mapping the arrow of $\Delta^1$ to an isomorphism of $\mathrm{h}\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something in the above argument, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: I think this line of argument can be completed by observing/checking that the obvious square with vertices $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^I$, $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^{\Delta^1}$, $\mathcal C^I$ and $\mathcal C^{\Delta^1}$ is a pullback of simplicial sets. Thus if $f$ lies in $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)$, the fibre of $\mathcal C^I\rightarrow\mathcal C^{\Delta^1}$ over $f$ is the same as the fibre of $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^I\rightarrow\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^{\Delta^1}$ over $f$. It is thus a contractible Kan complex as the latter map is a trivial Kan fibration.

Comment: For clarity, I feel like this argument doesn't come to a precise conclusion at the end -- the statement I think I can extract from the last line is that an equivalence $f$ can be viewed as an object of $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^{\Delta^1}$, and the fibre of $\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^I\rightarrow\mathrm{Core}(\mathcal C)^{\Delta^1}$ over $f$ is a contractible Kan complex. This definitely answers the vague version of the question, but a little extra argument is needed to answer the precise version (e.g. as in my above comment).

Comment: P.S. As I'm new to MO, I'm not sure what the accepted thing to do is: should I add an extra argument to this answer to link back to the precise question, or should I write this in a separate answer? I'm happy to follow Hurkyl's lead on this, and do whichever they would prefer!